# Jquery UI use object multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend

I need to display different amount of Date Pickers. Forms are generated dynamic, so I can't predict how many Datepickers I will use. Is it possible to use one id for all inputs?

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).mask("9999-99-99");
<input type="text" name="startDate1" value="" id="datepicker" >
<input type="text" name="startDate2" value="" id="datepicker" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UKbuC/

Comment: It is not a good practice to use the same id. You can define class which you can use for all the fields, and select them by class name.

Answer (score 2):

No. You shouldn't have more than element with the same id. In jquery, a better way would be to give them all a class of 'datepicker' and use the selector '.datepicker' instead.

```
<input type="text" name="startDate1" value="" class="datepicker" >
<input type="text" name="startDate2" value="" class="datepicker" >

$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).mask("9999-99-99");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one **class** instead of id for all the inputs and bind the datepicker using the class name.

```
// bind datepicker using class name
$(".mydatepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).mask("9999-99-99");

<input type="text" name="startDate1" value="" class="mydatepicker" >
<input type="text" name="startDate2" value="" class="mydatepicker" >
```